# Как обновить Array перед выходом из TableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8

Скажите пожалуйста как обновить Array перед выходом из `TableViewController`

***файл .h***

```
@interface DaysTableViewController : UITableViewController{
    NSArray * indexPathArray;
    IBOutlet UITableView *tableViewList;
}
```

***файл .m***

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    indexPathArray = [tableViewList indexPathsForSelectedRows];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    indexPathArray = [tableViewList indexPathsForSelectedRows];
}
```

Comment: что такое выход?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko - это когда выбираете дни когда должен зазвучать будильник и выходите из списка дней, если не понятно смотрите [тут](http://www.solveyourtech.com/create-iphone-alarm-goes-everyday/) step 5 - перед тем как выйти нужно обновить массив - вопрос как это сделать, пытался так -
`(void)viewWillDisappear{
    NSLog(@"%@", indexPathArray);
    [tableViewList reloadData];
}` 
но ничего не афиширует при выходе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если правильно понял - нужно передать данные на другой контроллер перед выходом с вью. Можно например использовать метод:

```
- (void)viewWillDisapper {
    [super viewWillDisapper];
    [self.delegate setSelectedRows:tableViewList. indexPathsForSelectedRows]; // заметим, что их не нужно даже хранить в промежуточной переменной
}
```

Тут `delegate` - это получатель данных. Но на самом деле тебе нужно хорошенько разобраться с тем, как организован MVC в CocoaTouch, например покачать примеры с сайта Apple, или почитать простейшие статьи по передаче данных между контроллерами. Без понимания MVC к правильному решению прийти сложно